# AWS API throws (503) Server Unavailable Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-net

In an EB environment I am getting these errors from worker Instances, who access the SQS queues through AWS API to check for new messages. It just started since 4-5 days and comes constantly every hour, Is it due to some network issue from AWS side??

Update#: No Issues in PHD affecting our region where this is deployed.

```
    An exception of type HttpErrorResponseException was handled in ErrorHandler.Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetResponse() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_bcl\HttpWebRequestFactory.cs:line 106
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetResponse() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_bcl\HttpWebRequestFactory.cs:line 114
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:line 85
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Unmarshaller.cs:line 48
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\SQS\Custom\Internal\ValidationResponseHandler.cs:line 28
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 72
```

And This:

```
An exception of type WebException was handled in ErrorHandler.System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetResponse() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_bcl\HttpWebRequestFactory.cs:line 118
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:line 85
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Unmarshaller.cs:line 48
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\SQS\Custom\Internal\ValidationResponseHandler.cs:line 28
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 72
```

Comment: You can check https://phd.aws.amazon.com/phd/home#/event-log to see all AWS issues that could affect your infrastructure.

Comment: No Issues in PHD affecting out region where this is deployed.

Comment: Either request throttling or a temporary server-side issue. Resend the request after a short wait.

Comment: It still continues to randomly error.  AWS forum asking for a request ID, and cloudtrail logs dont show anything with EventSource: sqs.amazonaws.com